# Como colocar valores em gráficos de barra com facetas no R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estou tentando gerar um gráfico em barras facetado com o R, conforme data frame e comandos abaixo:

```
   ###############################################
    ######___PACKGES UTILIZADOS_____###############
    ###############################################

    install.packages("plyr")
    library(plyr)

    install.packages("ggplot2")
    library(ggplot2)

    install.packages("ggthemes")
    library(ggthemes)

###############################################
######____DATA FRAME____________###############
###############################################

uf <- c("AC","AC","AC","AC","AC","AC","AC","AC","AM","AM","AM","AM","AM","AM","AM","AM")
da <- c("Federal", "Estadual", "Municipal", "Privada","Federal", "Estadual", "Municipal", "Privada","Federal", "Estadual", "Municipal", "Privada","Federal", "Estadual", "Municipal", "Privada")
tr <- c(97,99,90.5,78.6,3,1,9.5,21.4,97.2,99.1,96.8,98.7,2.8,0.9,3.2,1.3)
resposta <- c("resposta","resposta","resposta","resposta","não resposta","não resposta","não resposta","não resposta","resposta","resposta","resposta","resposta","não resposta","não resposta","não resposta","não resposta")

taxa <- data.frame(uf, da, tr,resposta)

O primeiro gráfico em facetas é gerado, conforme abaixo.

###############################################
######___BASIC GRAPHICS_____###############
###############################################

g1 <- ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(y = tr, x = da, fill = resposta), data = taxa, 
                          stat="identity")
g1 <- g1 + facet_grid(.~uf)
g1

[![Dependência administrativa por taxa de resposta][1]][1]


Depois eu acrescento os valores dentro das barras, mas ficam desajustados

###############################################
######___Adding data labels_____###############
###############################################

g1 <- g1 + geom_text(data=taxa, aes(x = da, y = tr, label = tr), size=4)
g1 <- g1 + facet_grid(.~uf)
g1
```

[image: Gráfico de barras com valores desalinhados]

Por fim, eu tento centralizar os valores, por meio da função dpply do plyr, conforme abaixo:

```
#####################################################
######_Adjusting data labels position_###############
#####################################################

taxa <- ddply(taxa, .(da), transform, pos = cumsum(tr) - (0.5 * tr)) # Ajusta a posição

g1 <- ggplot()+ geom_bar(aes(y = tr, x = da, fill = resposta), data = taxa, 
                          stat="identity") +
                facet_wrap(~uf) +
                geom_text(data=taxa, aes(x = da, y = pos, label = tr), size=4) + 
                theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.direction="horizontal", 
                 legend.title = element_blank())

g1
```

Entretanto, o gráfico fica desconfigurado, com valores fora da barra e a variável y indo até 200. O que está errado?

[image: Gráfico em barras facetado, mas desconfigurado]

Desde já agradeço

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que você precisa fazer neste caso é calcular a posição central de cada coluna antes de fazer o gráfico e então usar este valor como `y` do `geom_text`. Esse cálculo é simples mas pode ser chato de derivar, eu copiei a formuleta [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6645506/724200).

Usando `dplyr` fica mais simples. Você precisa agrupar pelos fatores que separam as colunas, e então criar uma nova coluna (utilizando o data frame `taxa` antes do ddply):

```
taxa %<>% group_by(uf, da) %>%
  mutate(pos = cumsum(tr) - 0.5*tr)
```

Depois é só plotar. Dei uma ajeitada no seu código do `ggplot` pra ficar mais sucinto, mas é essencialmente o mesmo, salvo a mudança do `y` do `geom_text`:

```
ggplot(taxa, aes(x = da, y = tr)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = resposta), stat = "identity") + 
  geom_text(aes(y = pos, label = tr), size = 4) + 
  facet_grid( . ~ uf)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

PS.: Pra fazer isso você não precisará do `plyr` e en nenhum momento neste código você precisou do `ggthemes`.